# How to fix midi inputfilestream error in JUCE?

Tags: readfile, midi, juce

I am trying to read the midi file into a sequence in JUCE, but when I run it, there is an error showed up saying there is something wrong with my inputfilestream.

I started from the audio-application template and write the midi read-in code in getNextBlock() function.

```
File midiPath("/Desktop/input.midi");
FileInputStream myStream(midiPath);
MidiFile midifile;
midifile.readFrom(myStream);
int NumofTrack = midifile.getNumTracks();
std::cout<<"The track number:"<<NumofTrack<<std::end;
```

I just wanna test the readin function in the JUCE, and it doesn't work. The error showed as "juce_FileInputStream.cpp":

```cpp
int64 FileInputStream::getTotalLength()
{
    // You should always check that a stream opened successfully before using it!
    jassert (openedOk());              <--  errror here
    ...
```

Comment: Have you verified that there's a file `input.midi` at the absolute path `/Desktop/`? I suspect that your path specification is wrong.

Comment: you are right, I find my silly mistake! the midi path should be "xxx.mid" rather than  "xxx.midi". Thanks for your message.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
File midiPath = File::getSpecialLocation(File::SpecialLocationType::userDesktopDirectory).getChildFile("input.midi");
FileInputStream myStream(midiPath);
MidiFile midifile;
midifile.readFrom(myStream);
int NumofTrack = midifile.getNumTracks();
std::cout<<"The track number:"<<NumofTrack<<std::end;
```